# Unlink and SplFileObject

Tags: php, file, unlink, splfileobject

Is it possible to unlink a file from an SplFileObject?

I don't see a method to close the underlying resource, and the file handle is private so one can't extend SplFileObject with that goal in mind.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: You could get the path with `SplFileObject::getPathName()`, unset the `SplFileObject` (which I *assume* closes the handle) then `unlink` the path that you got.

Comment: Unlinking a file doesn't require that all file handles be closed. You can very well still read and write to a file, even if the filename has been removed.

Answer (score 11):

I would not recommend this, because PHP closes the file behind scenes for you. If you take a look at the php src, `ext/spl/spl_directory.c`:

```
retval.handle = zend_objects_store_put(intern, 
  (zend_objects_store_dtor_t) zend_objects_destroy_object, 
  (zend_objects_free_object_storage_t) spl_filesystem_object_free_storage, 
   NULL TSRMLS_CC);
```

A handler is setup in order to deal with the cleanup of the object when all references have been exhausted. Now, we check the cleanup handler: `spl_filesystem_object_free_storage`:

```
    case SPL_FS_FILE:
        if (intern->u.file.stream) {
            if (intern->u.file.zcontext) {
/*              zend_list_delref(Z_RESVAL_P(intern->zcontext));*/
            }
            if (!intern->u.file.stream->is_persistent) {
                php_stream_free(intern->u.file.stream, PHP_STREAM_FREE_CLOSE);
            } else {
                php_stream_free(intern->u.file.stream, PHP_STREAM_FREE_CLOSE_PERSISTENT);
            }
            if (intern->u.file.open_mode) {
                efree(intern->u.file.open_mode);
            }
            if (intern->orig_path) {
                efree(intern->orig_path);
            }
        }
        spl_filesystem_file_free_line(intern TSRMLS_CC);
        break;
```

The `php_stream_free` call will close the file stream for you. If you unlink the file, I can't guarantee how PHP will handle trying to close the file handle you just linked.

You have to keep in mind what the SplFileObject provides you:

```
SplFileObject extends SplFileInfo implements RecursiveIterator , Traversable , Iterator , SeekableIterator {
```

It's provides many iterator based interfaces for a file. If you `unlink` the file, what is it supposed to iterate over? You'll notice that `close()` is not present in the available methods either. If you want to do what you're saying, then you're better off handling the file as a resource, where you can `close()` the handle and make it usable with `unlink()`, saving from nasty side effects.