# SplFileObject vs fopen in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, fopen, spl, splfileobject

What are the pros and cons of using `fopen` as opposed to `SplFileObject` in PHP?

From what I see, `SplFileObject` throws exceptions where applicable which makes this convenient when using `try...catch` for error handling. Apart from this, are there any other reasons to recommend one over the other?

(Bonus: Why is it called `SplFileObject`? What does `Spl` stand for? Why not simply `FileObject`?)

**Update:** One limitation of the `SplFileObject` is that it does not (yet) have a `close` member function. In some scenarios this can be a problem (Example: [Unlink and SplFileObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066145/unlink-and-splfileobject)).

Comment: you might wanna use the [spl] tag here. the few people who follow it are usually very enthusiastic & knowledgeable.

Answer (score 20):

SPL stands for Standard PHP Library.

`SplFileObject` uses internally the stream resource created with `fopen`. So your question should be when is it interesting to uses `SplFileObject` or to directly work with a stream resource ?

`SplFileObject` pros:

- `SplFileObject` provide an OOP approach to file manipulation (`fread` was added in PHP 5.5.11, `fputcsv` was added in PHP 5.4).
- `SplFileObject` implements several useful PHP Interfaces to enable the use of other [SPL Iterator](http://php.net/spl.iterators.php) to better manipulate your file.

`SplFileObject` main disadvantage is that it does not give access to its 
internal stream resource. PHP functions were originally build to directly work with a stream resource. The fact that the `SplFileObject` does not give access to its own internal stream resource make it unusable with many PHP built in functions:

- [php stream filters](http://php.net/stream) usage is poor with `SplFileObject`. You need to relies on the `php://filter` meta wrapper, which limits their usefulness.
- using `SplFileObject` with `cURL` is not possible

To sum it up `SplFileObject` and a stream resource are not interchangeable. **Anything done using `SplFileObject` could be achieved using a stream resource and a `SplFileObject` userland implementation but the reverse is not true**.

So depending on the use case using a stream resource created by `fopen` can be a better choice than relying on `SplFileObject`.

As for the close method, you don't need one... you just need to set the handler to null to release/close the internal stream resource.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('/path/to/my/file'); //the file handler is created
$file = null; //the file handler is closed
```

Answer (score 4):

Spl stands for Standard PHP Library.

The main advantage is the object orientation, which is more suitable for some approaches (not for everything, that is). It is a good option if you have to provide classes for handling files (as in custom formats, etc.) as you can inherit from `SplFileObject` and have the basic functionality already built in.

The main question here is what you want to achieve with your code - do you need to open a single file once, read it's data and then work with it or do you need to do more complex stuff with one (or even more) files.

Comment: I have this one page in my project where I load a CSV file and populate a database. I am using a `try... catch` in every page for error handling. Am I right in thinking that `SplFileObject` is a good choice here?

Comment: I'd personally prefer it for data which you want to put into your database, as you can do finer error handling, so I would go for that myself in this general setting, as I would like to log errors, etc.. However, if you can be sure about the file inputs (not broken, from an automated source, etc.) you could probably go for `fgetscsv`

Answer (score 1):

Spl is a standard library in Php making a lot of nice stuff.

One good reason using a SplFileObject is that it makes your code Object Oriented. If you want, you can extend the class in your own code base and make it do some nice stuff while using files, with already the basics covered.